# JQuery - hide and view strings

Tags: jquery, contains

I need to set a specific view for my print view on my website. I have one table with users from a mysql database.

Desktop View

```
First Name | Last Name  | Status
----------------------------------
Lorem      | Ipsum      | Admin
AA         | BB         | Member
BB         | CC         | Member
DD         | EE         | Member
GG         | HH         | Guest
JJ         | KK         | Guest
```

structure of the view is a simple table:

```
table 
thead > tr > th (First Name,..)
tbody > tr > td (Lorem ...)
tbody > tr > td > a (Member)
```

For the Print View i need this

```
Admin
Lorem   | Ipsum

Member
AA      | BB    
BB      | CC    
DD      | EE    

Guest
GG      | HH        
JJ      | KK
```

is there a jquery solution to say if "td > a" contains word "Member" then hide the rest td's that contains "Member" and so on...? The number of users are not static!

Comment: you want to remove duplicate entries or what?

Comment: yes for the print view.

Comment: but from your question and example you totally changed the structure of table. am i right? to totally change the table structure?

Comment: yes the table structure will be changed maybe with css3...(but this is not the problem :) )

Comment: print view means browser's print view or, do you have a function that would print the data and download as pdf or excel?

Comment: @yeyene no function, just print view with the browser

Answer (score 0):

Create print.css file and attach it in header section.

```
<link href="style/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" charset="utf-8" />
```

Then add in this in print.css file.

## CSS

```
td.yourStatusColumClass {display:none;}
```

But, this will only hide your status column, you still need to modify the style you want.

Comment: but this hides all status, i need it once for every section

Comment: yes, you can prepare status header (like in your print view), hide it in desktop view. Then show it again in print view.

Comment: the number of users are not static so i cant say insert status column after 3 rows....